# What to do if the righthand of a constraint is a variable when solving Linear programs?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming, simplex

I'm starting to solve linear program exercises with the Simplex method.

$$max \ (3x_1-x_2)$$
$$\begin{cases}
x_1-x_2 \le 3\\
2x_1\le x_2\\
x_1+x_2\ge 12\\
x_2 \le 10\\
x_1,x_2 \ge 0
\end{cases}$$

I transform it to the standard form...

$$\begin{cases}
x_1-x_2 + x_3 = 3\\
\color{red}{2x_1 + 0 + 0 + x_4 = x_2}\\
x_1+x_2 + 0 + 0 - x_5 = 12\\
0 + x_2 + 0 + 0 + 0 + x_6 = 10\\
x_1,x_2 \ge 0
\end{cases}$$

Look at the second row. The righthand of the equation is $x_2$.

It is my understanding that the righthand of the constraints must be non-negative so this program can be in standard form. Since it is $x_2$ in the second row, this isn't necessarily the case.

I imagined that I should simply move the $x_2$ to the left side. However I am hesitant do that, because I guess that affects the matrix and hence the result. What exactly should one do in this scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the original problem you simply rewrite the second inequality as

$$2x_1-x_2\le 0$$

Comment: Ha... Goddammit.